# How to use OR Condition in twig and symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

```
{% if ( session.get('userRole') != 'ROLE CLIENT USER' ) or  ( session.get('actionPermission') == 'true' ) %}

    {# do stuff #}

{% endif; %}
```

Comment: Try changing `{% endif; %}` to `{% endif %}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{% if (session.get('userRole') != 'ROLE CLIENT USER' or  session.get('actionPermission') == 'true') %}

    {# ... do stuff #}

{% endif %}
```